# Accessing a UserControl's resource from itself

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, resourcedictionary

Is it possible to access a defined resource in a `UserControl` from itself? How?

I'm trying to do this:

```
<UserControl xmlns="all defined namespaces here..."
             Visibility="{Binding Show,FallbackValue=Hidden,
                 Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibility" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

, but I get this error:

> 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an
>   exception.' Line number '11' and line position '9'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can probably change the order:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibility" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Visibility>
    <Binding Path="Show" FallbackValue="Hidden"
             Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}"/>
</UserControl.Visibility>
```

You could also move the converter to the `Application.Resources` as it's commonly used in multiple places, then it can be referenced anywhere.